Can't render data from supabase to react native mobile app
i have created my table in supabase 
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Pressable,
  FlatList,
  ActivityIndicator,
} from "react-native";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { supabase } from "../supabaseClient"; // Ensure the correct path
import { useAuthentication } from "../hooks/useAuthentication";
import AntDesign from "@expo/vector-icons/AntDesign";

export default function Home({ navigation }) {
  const { isAuthenticated, logout } = useAuthentication();
  const [agriculteurs, setAgriculteurs] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const handleLogout = () => {
    logout(navigation);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        let { data: Type_Agriculteur, error } = await supabase
          .from("Type_Agriculteur")
          .select("*");

        if (error) {
          console.error("Supabase error:", error);
        } else {
          setAgriculteurs(data);
          console.log("Fetched data:", data);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <Text style={styles.itemText}>
        {item.Type_ID} {item.Type}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Pressable onPress={handleLogout} style={styles.logoutButton}>
        <AntDesign name="logout" size={24} color="black" />
      </Pressable>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Home</Text>
      <View>
        {loading ? (
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
        ) : (
          <FlatList
            data={agriculteurs}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.Type_ID.toString()}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    padding: 16,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 24,
    marginBottom: 16,
    textAlign: "center",
  },
  logoutButton: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: 50,
    right: 10,
  },
  item: {
    padding: 16,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: "#ccc",
  },
  itemText: {
    fontSize: 18,
  },
});

when i run the app i get this error :
error fetching data: TypeError: Can not read property 'from' of undefined
what i cant understand is that all the imports are there but the code just keeps bugging
AI BOTS keep teling me to check supabase keys but the issus cant be comming from there since the authentication is working just fine

You can try importing supabase in the superbase client this way:            import * as sb from

thanks man the issue was that i imported it as a named import
